# Chrome displays transparent gif/png background of image as white

Tags: css, google-chrome, png, transparency, gif

I am starting a new webpage at draincleaningphx.com, and the eagle image on the homepage using Chrome still displays the transparent background as white. Ive tried the image saved as both png and gif file. I've read about using css to make the background transparent but can't figure it out.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Eagle image is transparent.
If you put any other color in the CSS for the content:

```
#content {
float: right;
width: 640px;
margin-right: 30px;
background-color: #000;
}
```

for example black, you can see, the image is transparent.
If you want to add the shadow to eagle, you need edit to picture with shadow around the eagle :D

Answer (score -2):

Did you just open the image in the browser or did you embed it in a HTML file / defined as background-image?